# PyQt5 QTextBrowser - setText - Alignment issue?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextbrowser

I am trying to make a simple GUI console using PyQt5. On trying to print the text using QTextBrowser - setText, it loses alignment and looks bad. but the text is aligned in my python console

I am using the setText function to display my data frame.
On changing the justify parameter of df.to_string(), i am able to see the changed alignment in the python console, but this is not reflected in my Qt console.

Code :

```
import sys
from GUI_4 import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import New_Read_Map_File

def window():    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()   
    label = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(MainWindow)                    
    label.setStyleSheet('color: blue')    
    MainWindow.setGeometry(600,150,800,800)
    label.setGeometry(10,10,780,780)    
    GetData()
    label.setText(DisplayData)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())    

def GetData():
    global DisplayData
    New_Read_Map_File.read_MapFile_main()
    DisplayData = (New_Read_Map_File.df.to_string(col_space = 14,justify = "justify"))    
    print(DisplayData)


window()
```

Expected Alignment

[image]

Observed Qt GUI

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the font, in the case of consoles and many IDES use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces).

For example, if you use the Monospace font:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

def pandas_to_str():
    df = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'A' : 1.,
        'B' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
        'C' : pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32'),
        'D' : np.array([3] * 4,dtype='int32'),
        'E' : pd.Categorical(["test","train","test","train"]),
        'F' : 'foo' })
    return df.to_string(col_space =14,justify = "justify")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
    w.setStyleSheet('color: blue') 
    w.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Monospace"))
    w.setWordWrapMode(QtGui.QTextOption.NoWrap)
    w.setText(pandas_to_str())
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response and edits eyllanesc, I tried changing the font..Still, the issue persists.

Comment: I had tried Monospace as you had suggested. Also, used the alignment options QtGui.QTextOption.NoWrap from your code. There was no effect. Then, I tried to use Arial. I am able to see the changed font.. but the alignment is still corupt... Thank you for this overwhelming support... :)

Comment: Thank you so much.... as you had mentioned, the problem was that the font was not installed. I adapted the font from your github link and it worked swiftly....... You're awesome..!! - Pawan

Comment: could you provide information how to install font, I don't see the github link